# Best way to randomize a binary diagonal matrix, keeping 1's off diagonal

Tags: r, permutation

Let A be an n*n diagonal matrix. Say, n=5:

```
A <- diag(1, 5)
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

I need to randomize `A` by rows, keeping the 1's off the diagonal. I figured out this solution:

```
n <- 5
count <- c(1:n)
for (i in count) {
  while (A[count[i], count[i]] == 1) {    #avoid 1 in diagonal
    A[count[i],] <- sample(A[count[i],])  #permutes ith row
  }
}
```

but I am pretty sure that there should be a more efficient way of doing this. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you just mean that you want a single one in each row, but not on the diagonal?

Comment: Correct. This is exactly the point.

Comment: Do you not also want a `1` in each column? I see that @jbaums answer does not preserve that property.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants this, @flodel, since the approach provided in the question doesn't observe the constraint.

Comment: However, it would be also useful to have a solution for flodel's proposition. Just in case and if it is not much to ask.

Comment: I've updated my solution to include an approach that allows only a single `1` per column-row combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sample a random number from the integer sequence `1:n`, `n` times, but each time exclude the cell number that corresponds to the diagonal.

One way to do this is as follows:

```
n <- 5
rnd <- sample(n-1, repl=T)
i <- c(rnd + (rnd >= seq_len(n-1)) * 1, sample(n-1, 1))  

i
# [1] 3 3 4 5 1
```

Here, each element of `i` is prevented from being equal to the element's index (e.g. element 1 cannot be 1, element 2 cannot be 2, etc.). We can consider each element of `i` to be the selected column for each row in turn.

Next we set up a matrix of zeroes, and (for the above example) fill the cells `[1, 3]`, `[2, 3]`, `[3, 4]`, `[4, 5]` and `[5, 1]` to 1.

```
m <- matrix(0, nc=n, nr=n)
m[cbind(seq_len(n), i)] <- 1

m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    1
# [5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

The final row of code uses matrix subsetting to subset the matrix `m` to the relevant cells.

---

**EDIT**

In order to ensure that each column *and* each row have only a single `1`, and that these are kept off the diagonal, the following vectorised approach will work. The trick here is to permute the vector `n-1`, and consider each element of that permuted vector to be the index, for each row, of the `n-1` non-diagonal elements that we will assign `1`. We then check, for each element of our permuted vector, whether the value is less than the index of the diagonal for the corresponding row. If so, we leave the element as is, otherwise we add 1. This determines the column indices for the first `n-1` rows. The index for the final row is then simply the index of the column that does not yet have a `1`.

```
n <- 5
rnd <- sample(n-1)

i <- union(rnd + (rnd >= seq_len(n-1)) * 1, seq_len(n))

m <- matrix(0, nc=n, nr=n)
m[cbind(seq_len(n), i)] <- 1

m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [4,]    1    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    1    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It does exactly what I wanted

Comment: After adding the second part of this solution, I realised that a similar approach can be applied to the first part. I've updated it accordingly since it's much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks again. You are awsome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best or most elegant, but you can choose a random (but non diagonal) element with which to replace the diagonal element on each row, and then assign the non-diagonals with the remainder:

```
count <- c(1:n)
for (i in count) {
    off <- sample(count[-i],1)
    perm <- sample(count[-off])
    tmp <- A[i,off]
    A[i, count[-i]] <- A[i,perm]
    A[i,i] <- tmp
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting. I have tried it and it seems to work the way it should. Still I prefer the second answer becasue it avoids the for loop.

Comment: No problem - just be aware that as written, this one will work for general diagonal matrices, not just identity matrices - the other, rather more elegant, approach will need the final `<- 1` to be changed

Comment: I see your point and have given a vote to your answer. Thanks again.